# Learn c the hard way ex29 compiling/linking problem

Tags: c

I have a github [repo](https://github.com/NEOdinok/lcthw_ex29) representing my exercise folder. Upon running `make all` the compiler throws error messages saying (Ubuntu):

```
cc -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -DNDEBUG  -fPIC   -c -o src/libex29.o src/libex29.c
src/libex29.c: In function ‘fail_on_purpose’:
src/libex29.c:36:33: warning: unused parameter ‘msg’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int fail_on_purpose(const char* msg)
                                 ^~~
ar rcs build/libex29.a src/libex29.o
ranlib build/libex29.a
cc -shared -o build/libex29.so src/libex29.o
cc -g -Wall -Wextra -Isrc     test/ex29_test.c   -o test/ex29_test
/tmp/cc7dbqDt.o: In function `main':
/home/givi/Desktop/lcthw_dir/29/test/ex29_test.c:21: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/home/givi/Desktop/lcthw_dir/29/test/ex29_test.c:22: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/home/givi/Desktop/lcthw_dir/29/test/ex29_test.c:25: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/home/givi/Desktop/lcthw_dir/29/test/ex29_test.c:26: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/home/givi/Desktop/lcthw_dir/29/test/ex29_test.c:33: undefined reference to `dlclose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'test/ex29_test' failed
make: *** [test/ex29_test] Error 1
```

i spent quite a lot trying to figure out how to `fix undefined references`. dlfcn.h is included, everything seems to be ok. Am i missing something? Please help

Comment: The failing command is `ld`, the linkage editor, so it appears that the problem is that you're missing the library which contains the object code for `dlopen`, etc.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica answers weren't very helpful so far but i learned that the problem is that i have to put -ldl flag somewhere in the Makefile to make it all link properly. Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You must add following option when linking code using [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) :

```
-ldl
```

Here is a demo for Ubuntu 18:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
$ cat dl.c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    void *r;

    r = dlopen("", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (r != NULL)
        printf("r is not null \n");

    return 0;
}
$ gcc -o dl -Wall -pedantic -std=c11 dl.c -ldl
$ echo $?
0
```

Here is a very simple Makefile(note position of `-ldl`) and related make commands:

```
$ cat Makefile
CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -DNDEBUG $(OPTFLAGS) $(OPTLIBS)  

dl.o    :dl.c
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS)

dl  :dl.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) -ldl

clean   : 
    rm -f dl dl.o
$ make clean
rm -f dl dl.o
$ make dl
cc -c dl.c -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -DNDEBUG    
dl.c: In function ‘main’:
dl.c:5:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
              ^~~~
dl.c:5:27: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
                           ^~~~
cc -o dl dl.o -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -DNDEBUG     -ldl
$ ./dl
r is not null
```

Comment: my Makefile already contains the following 
CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -DNDEBUG $(OPTFLAGS)
LIBS=-ldl $(OPTLIBS)

Comment: It's usually `LDLIBS` in Makefile, the builtin linking command is something like this: `${CC} ${LDFLAGS} -o $@ $^ ${LDLIBS}`

Answer (score 0):

Usually the references you're missing can be resolved by adding linker flag `-ldl`.

You didn't mention which operating system you're using.
In case you're on Windows you'll need this library: https://github.com/dlfcn-win32/dlfcn-win32

Comment: my Makefile already contains the following 
CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -DNDEBUG $(OPTFLAGS)
LIBS=-ldl $(OPTLIBS)

Comment: Make sure `$(LIBS)` in your Makefile isn't placed before the `.o` files on the line(s) where linking happens. Order is important on Windows.

Note that in your message above `-ldl` is not present in the link command: `cc -g -Wall -Wextra -Isrc     test/ex29_test.c   -o test/ex29_test`

Comment: cc -g -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -ldl      test/ex29_test.c   -o test/ex29_test Still does not work. I'm on Ubuntu btw

Comment: You may need to add `-ldl` at the end of `gcc` command line so that it works on Ubuntu (see my updated answer).

Comment: What happens if you build with `-static` ?

Comment: @pifor would you please give the exact location in my Makefile that i have to modify to make it all work ? I'm just beating around the bush putitng -ldl here and there but it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Neodinok: I have added a Makefile example that works (not sure it is a very good example of Makefile but it does work on Ubuntu 18.0.4.4,  gcc 7.5.0 and gmake 4.1).